# Find a Word within Cell, then Replace Entire Cell with New Word?

Tags: regex, excel, replace, notepad++

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 300 entries.

There's a 100 mix of cells that contain the following word - Bandwidth.

Some cells says the following:

```
Bandwidth 1
Bandwidth Check
Bandwidth Field
Bandwidth Out
Bandwidth In
etc (with random numbers)
```

Here's what I want to do:

If the cell contains "Bandwidth" (like the above samples) then I want to replace whatever is in there with just the word "Bandwidth."

So the columns will say:

Bandwidth
Bandwidth
Bandwidth
Bandwidth
Bandwidth
Bandwidth
etc...

A Find and Replace of "Bandwidth" just changes that word and keeps the other text. I want to find where it appears and replace the entire cell with "Bandwidth."

Can this be done with Excel or Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ Replace `Bandwidth.+` with `Bandwidth` (Regular expression) should suit. Can be done within Excel but requires an Add-In.

For Find what: use `.+[Bandwidth].+` for stripping out text before as well as after.

Comment: That worked great for "Bandwidth & _____" but, is there another way to make it so that it removes text before it as well? do I try Bandwidth.- ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub CleanUp()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String, v As String
    s = "Bandwidth"
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, s) > 0 Then
            r.Value = s
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great in excel! It removed both the text before and after perfectly... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Find: .*?(Bandwidth).*?
Replace: $1
```

Make sure that regex is checked.

Comment: This works great in removing the text before "Bandwidth" but what about after as well? thanks!

Comment: @user2752620: The text after will be removed as well.